# Blazor component throws exception when controller returns 401

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have a login component which posts user details to a login controller, if the request was successful it returns a 200 with the result to add the identity token to the cookies. If the result wasn't successful, it returns a 401 with the result (which in this case will contain the errors). For some reason Blazor is throwing the following exception when I return the 401 but the 200 works fine.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
    Unhandled exception rendering component: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

LoginController:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginUserCommand command)
{
    var response = await Mediator.Send(command);

    if (!response.Result.Succeeded) return Unauthorized(response);

    return Ok(response);
}
```

LoginComponent:

```
private async Task HandleLogin()
{
    _showErrors = false;

    var result = await AuthService.Login(_command);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        _loginHidden = true;
        AppState.SetPage(string.Empty);
    }
    else
    {
        _errors = result.Errors;
        _showErrors = true;
    }
}
```

AuthService:

```
public async Task<Result> Login(LoginUserCommand command)
{
    var response = await _httpClient.PostNewtonsoftJsonAsync<(Result Result, string Token)>("api/login", command);

    if (!response.Result.Succeeded) return response.Result;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Token)) await SetAuthToken(command.Email, response.Token);

    return response.Result;
}
```

PostNewtonsoftJsonAsync is just PostJsonAsync but forced to used Newtonsoft as you can't serialize a value tuple this way using `System.Text.Json`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that PostNewtonsoftJsonAsync had `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` in it which was causing the exception.